# How to append items in list which starts with alphabet python

Tags: python

Find a sublist which starts with alphabet in python 3? 
how to append items in list which starts with alphabet python

```
import re

 code_result =  [['1', 'abc_123', '0.40','7.55'], ['paragraph', '100', 'ML MY'],
               ['2','abc_456', '0.99'], ['letters and words','end','99']] 

index_list = []
sub_list = []

for i in range(0,len(code_result)): 
   if code_result[i][0].isalpha():
       index_list.append([i,i-1]) 

for item in range(0,len(index_list)): 
   temp = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]','',str(code_result[index_list[item][0]]))
   sub_list.append([code_result[index_list[item][1]][1]+" "+temp])
   print(sub_list)
```

My code works only for one alphabet in the sublist not more than that

```
 Expected Output:
    [['abc_123 paragraph 100 MLMY'],['abc_456 letters and words end 99']]
```

Comment: can you explain your expected output? It is not clear from the example what is the logic

Comment: What is the problem with your code ?

Comment: My code works only for one alphabet in the sublist not more than that. it not included the space 2 words

Comment: guys please tell me why are you giving negative votes

Comment: Because you neither specify what you're trying to achieve nor your problem.

Comment: How to append items in list which starts with alphabet python

Comment: @pyml does 100 start with alphabet? Does 99? Why do you only add 'abc_123' from the 1st list but take all of 2nd? Your ask one thing in your question, but your code does completely different. At least try using google translate to convey your task in detail instead of giving keywords like a robot `answer = how(["list", "start", "alphabet", "append", "python"])` .

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need with minimal changes

```
import re
code_result = [['1', 'abc_123', '0.40','7.55'], ['paragraph', '100', 'ML MY'], ['2','abc_456', '0.99'], ['letters and words','end','99']]
index_list = []
sub_list = []
for i in range(0,len(code_result)):
   if code_result[i][0][0].isalpha():
      index_list.append([i,i-1])

for item in range(0,len(index_list)):
   temp = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z ]','',str(code_result[index_list[item][0]]))
   sub_list.append([code_result[index_list[item][1]][1]+" "+temp])
print(sub_list)
```

BUT I am still unclear of what you are trying to do and think this whatever it is it could've been done better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution, that ends up with your desired output, using the built-in `startswith` method (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)).

```
import re

code_result =  [['1', 'abc_123', '0.40','7.55'], ['paragraph', '100', 'ML MY'], ['2','abc_456', '0.99'], ['letters and words','end','99']] 

l1 = [] 
l2 = []
last = False

for x in code_result:
    if last:
        for y in range(len(x)):
            l1.append(x[y])
            if y == len(x)-1:
                l2.append([' '.join(l1)])
                l1 = []
                last = False
    else:
        for y in x:
            a = re.search('^[a-zA-Z]', y)
            if a:
                l1.append(y)
                last = True
                break

print(l2)
```

This code iterates over your list of lists, checks whether an item in a list starts with 'abc' and breaks the inner loop. If the `last` is `True`, it appends all items from the subsequent list.

Comment: Well, I still don't see how you come to your desired output with the condition you propose. However, I edited my answer and it should produce the output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Since only letters have an uppercase and lowercase variation, you could use that as a condition.  The whole thing could fit in a single list comprehension:

```
 sub_list = [[s for s in a if s[0].lower()!=s[0].upper()] for a in code_result]

 # [['abc_123'], ['paragraph', 'ML MY'], ['abc_456'], ['letters and words', 'end']]
```

Note that your problem statement and expected output are ambiguous.  they could also mean:

sub lists that start with an item that only contains letters (based on question title):

```
[ a  for a in code_result if a[0].lower()!=a[0].upper()]

# [['paragraph', '100', 'ML MY'], ['letters and words', 'end', '99']]
```

OR, based on the expected output, sub list elements that start with a letter, sometimes taken individually and other times using the whole sublist and arbitrarily concatenated into a single string within a sub list.

Comment: And thats not the desired output. However, since the the question (how to append items that start with alphabetic characaters) and the desired output diverge, pyml might be able to combine our answers to come to a solution.